# instantiate draft (i.e. prototype) of an object (e.g. turret) from factory without duplicating code

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

By depicting it with a game, it will make the problem most describable.

In a tower-defense game that the player can build many types of turret, 
here is a code of turret factory :-

```
Entity* createTurret(EnumTurretType turretType){
    Entity* turret = ...;
    switch(turretType){
        case FIRE_TURRET:{
            GraphicObject* fireCG=graphicFactory()->create(FIRE);
            //.... initialize a few mesh, and a few physic solid objects
            turret->attachComponent(GraphicObject);
        }break;
        case ICE_TURRET:{
            //......
        }break;
        //.... 20-30 types
    }
    return turret;
}
```

Everything is good so far.  Game is playable, and everyone is happy.

Now it is the step to let players build turret by using mouse, and it would be cool if the player can see silhouette (e.g. fade hologram) of turret while the mouse is moving around.

**Question:** How should it be implemented without duplicating the code?

---

---

### **My poor approaches**

**1. Create a real turret, then move the turret along with mouse**

The turret will function like the real one, crash with other turret and shoot - even it is just a prototype that is dragging around by the player.

An alleviation is to create a magic flag that make the turret as "prototyped" (aka. disabled).

This cure have to propagate among many game logic part - to check whether a certain turret was disable or not  ....  whether a bullet is collide with a "disabled" turret ...  so on.

It is tedious, induces bug, and reduce code readability and a bit of maintainability.

**2. Duplicate the above code, then remove non-relate stuff**

Copy-paste only Graphic's part.
If there is any graphic that is related to game-logic, it have to be re-hardcoded in graphic style.  For example :-

```
//pseudo-code
Physical gun will be 3 meter above the turret's base;
Draw graphical gun at the physical gun position;
```

... must be converted to ...

```
A graphical gun will be 3 meter above the turret's base;
```

I have to do it for every type of turret, and when turret's design change, I will have to update the other one too.

It will cause maintainability problem.

Comment: Make the graphics part and the action part independent classes usable on their own. Have the real turret class *reuse* both of the above classes by *inheritance* or *composition*.

Answer (score 1):

A an not sure if this is can be an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I think the first approach is good, if you don't want to propagate the logic, maybe you can just detach your collider from physical engine when disable the turrent if your physical engine doesn't support this, and for shoot, you will able to stop it.

And you need just re-enable your component when you enable the turrent.

Comment: Nice idea, thank.   I started to think that vast majority of the problem might be solved by modifying or disable only Physic's part within the factory.